# Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties metadata generation - wrong default values

Tags: spring-boot

So I'm trying to generate my own configuration metadata from @ConfigurationProperties items, following documentation available at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor. Note that I'm using Spring Boot 2.0 and Kotlin.

It works fine, except for one thing: the defaultValue fields are not getting filled with my default values, but instead just contain standard values like 0 or false.

My @ConfigurationProperties file looks like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("flowr.epg")
class EpgProperties {
    /** Whether or not schedules should be computed/refreshed on (re)start */
    var refreshOnRestart = true
    /** Number of threads used to store new images */
    var nImagesUploadThreads = 10
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
{
  "hints": [],
  "groups": [
    {
      "sourceType": "com.taktik.flowr.epg.properties.EpgProperties",
      "name": "flowr.epg",
      "type": "com.taktik.flowr.epg.properties.EpgProperties"
    }
  ],
  "properties": [
{
  "sourceType": "com.taktik.flowr.epg.properties.EpgProperties",
  "defaultValue": false,
  "name": "flowr.epg.refresh-on-restart",
  "description": "Whether or not schedules should be computed\/refreshed on (re)start",
  "type": "java.lang.Boolean"
},
{
  "sourceType": "com.taktik.flowr.epg.properties.EpgProperties",
  "defaultValue": 0,
  "name": "flowr.epg.n-images-upload-threads",
  "description": "Number of threads used to store new images in Ozone",
  "type": "java.lang.Integer"
}
}
```

The documentation is kind of poor about that defaultValue field. Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to fill that defaultValue field automatically? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be a limitation of the annotation processor when using Kotlin. Does it work for you if your `@ConfigurationProperties` class is written in Java?

Comment: Indeed, it does work with Java. So there is no solution for Kotlin?

Comment: I'm surprised it's done as well as it has given that it's a Java annotation processor and you have apparently pointed it at some Kotlin source code. Can you please open a [Spring Boot enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) and include a small sample that demonstrates the current behaviour?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that!

Comment: Thank you for opening https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15397.